# Concatenating C# string only when the pre check is an empty string

Tags: c#, coding-style, string-concatenation

I am kind of C# novice and I am trying to concatenate a string in C# to display the checked result in a textbox followed by a button click. I was able to get the desired output but the code seems it has not followed the DRY principle in SE.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String result1, result2="";

            if (radioButton1.Checked )
            {
                result1 = radioButton1.Text;
            }
            else if (radioButton2.Checked)
            {
                result1 = radioButton1.Text;
            }
            else if (radioButton3.Checked)
            {
                result1 = radioButton3.Text;
            }


            if (checkBox1.Checked)
            {
                result2 = checkBox1.Text;
            }
            if (checkBox2.Checked)
            {
                if (result2 != "")
                {
                    result2 = result2 + "," + checkBox2.Text;
                }
                else
                result2 = checkBox2.Text;
            }
            if (checkBox3.Checked)
            {
                if (result2 != "")
                {
                    result2 = result2 + "," + checkBox3.Text;
                }
                else
                result2 = checkBox3.Text;
            }

            textBox1.Text="You like to shop from "+ result1    
                           +"for clothing styles like "+result2;
       }
```

I am sure there should be a lot clever way of doing this and it would be highly appreciated if someone could provide me a better solution.

Comment: if there is no problem with your code and you want to optimize it, probably it will be good idea to post it on code review platform of stack overflow. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I was not aware about that thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be written in a single line (if your checkboxes are all contained in the controls collection of the form

```
result2 = string.Join(",", this.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>()
                .Where(x => x.Checked)
                .Select(c => c.Text));
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. For some reason result2 is getting assigned to an empty string all the time even though the check boxes are selected. I assume my checkboxes are all contained in the controls collection of the form.

Comment: Well, this is strange because I have tested it. Are you sure about the checkboxes? If they are inside a groupbox, a panel or a tabpage you need to use the controls collection of that control. IE `this.groupBox1.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>()......`

Answer (score 1):

How about using [String.Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx) and [String.Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1csw23d(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Something like

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String result1, result2="";

        if (radioButton1.Checked )
        {
            result1 = radioButton1.Text;
        }
        else if (radioButton2.Checked)
        {
            result1 = radioButton1.Text;
        }
        else if (radioButton3.Checked)
        {
            result1 = radioButton3.Text;
        }


        List<string> choices = new List<string>();
        if (checkBox1.Checked)
        {
            choices.Add(checkBox1.Text);
        }
        if (checkBox2.Checked)
        {
            choices.Add(checkBox2.Text);
        }
        if (checkBox3.Checked)
        {
            choices.Add(checkBox3.Text);
        }

        textBox1.Text=String.Format("You like to shop from {0} for clothing styles like {1}", result1, String.Join(",",choices.ToArray()));
   }
```